# How can I deploy wsps to SharePoint without downtime?

Tags: powershell, deployment

I have created a powershell script for deploying wsps to the SharePoint Farm. The script also uses psremoting to login remotely to the servers (WFE and Application servers) to recycle the application pools.

This works fine on the dev server but on UAT and PRD the applications pools on both WFE servers stop completely and have to be restarted manually.

Why is this happening?
How can I work around it to get 0 downtime.

Comment: Technically you won't be able to have 0 downtime as the app pools have to recycle, bringing down your farm and degrading performance while things spin back up

Comment: Ok but shouldn't the recycle just start a new process and transfer everything over to that with the exception of session information?                                                Any insight into why the WFE application pools stop but the Application server ones stay running?

Comment: Hi, any follow up?

Answer (score 0):

Aybe a little late, but I blogged about this

https://blog.bajonczak.com/deploy-sharepoint-solutions-without-downtime-really/

This will only work in farms, because you must have a good configured load balancer. So first you deploy the solution locally on server 1, after finishing and warming up the server 1,ypu will deploy it on the other server(s) also locally. So the load balancer will switch to the "healthy" ones.